# How can I add a GPS that leads to pins on map?

Tags: ios, swift, gps

I am making an app that displays pins ( that the user adds) on a map and saves them in a tableview and I would like to have a GPS lead the user when they tap on a button that opens the GPS so they can get to that place, how could I do this, this is the code I have in the table view:

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

        cell.textLabel?.text = places[indexPath.row]["name"]

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> NSIndexPath? {

        activePlace = indexPath.row

        return indexPath

    }
```

and this is the code I have in the map view:

```
func action(gestureRecognizer:UIGestureRecognizer) {

        if gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began {

            var touchPoint = gestureRecognizer.locationInView(self.Map)

            var newCoordinate = self.Map.convertPoint(touchPoint, toCoordinateFromView: self.Map)

            var location = CLLocation(latitude: newCoordinate.latitude , longitude: newCoordinate.longitude)



            CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(location, completionHandler: { (placemarks, error) -> Void in

                var title = ""

                if (error == nil) {



                    if let p = CLPlacemark(placemark: placemarks?[0] as! CLPlacemark) {

                        var subThoroughfare: String = ""
                        var thoroughfare: String = ""

                        if p.subThoroughfare != nil {

                            subThoroughfare = p.subThoroughfare

                        }

                        if p.thoroughfare != nil {

                            thoroughfare = p.thoroughfare
                        }

                        title = "\(subThoroughfare) \(thoroughfare)"

                    }

                }

                if title == "" {

                    title = "added \(NSDate())"
                }

                places.append(["name":title,"lat":"\(newCoordinate.latitude)","lon":"\(newCoordinate.longitude)"])
```

I have been trying the code below to add the GPS but I have a predefined destination so I suppose I have to change the coordinates to something else but I dont know exactly what, thanks for the help !

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "http://maps.apple.com/maps?daddr=34.539250,-117.222025")!)
```

I am also using this piece of code for the user location

```
 func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {

        var userLocation:CLLocation = locations[0] as! CLLocation

        var latitude = userLocation.coordinate.latitude
        var longitude = userLocation.coordinate.longitude

        var coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)

        var latDelta:CLLocationDegrees = 0.01
        var lonDelta:CLLocationDegrees = 0.01

        var span:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(latDelta, lonDelta)

        var region:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(coordinate, span)

        self.Map.setRegion(region, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To piggyback off of @Mingebag 's answer, in response to your comment there:
You need to set the variables in the openMapForPlace() method he provided to the ones that correspond to the gps position you want to get directions to in the apple maps app.

Wherever you call this method, you can pass it the variables you need. For this to work, you really just need to give it Lat / Lon somehow.
You could do that by making it be:

```
func openMapsForPlace(lat: Double, lon: Double) {}
```

or whatever format you have those in.

You can also just put this code wherever you want if you have a better place for it to execute from:

```
let regionDistance:CLLocationDistance = 10000

//set the coordinates with your variables
var coordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(newCoordinates.latitude, newCoordinates.longitude)
let regionSpan = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coordinates, regionDistance, regionDistance)
var options = [
    MKLaunchOptionsMapCenterKey: NSValue(MKCoordinate: regionSpan.center),
    MKLaunchOptionsMapSpanKey: NSValue(MKCoordinateSpan: regionSpan.span)
]

//now your placemark will have the lat long you put in above
var placemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinates, addressDictionary: nil) 

var mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: placemark)
mapItem.name = "\(self.venueName)"

//this line then launches the app for you
mapItem.openInMapsWithLaunchOptions(options)
```

Comment: Thanks it started working on my device and then said terminated due tu memory pressure on Xcode,( it was still running it just showed that message ) what could this come from ?

Comment: Maybe a retain cycle - google retain cycle and see if it looks like your problem. Otherwise maybe you are storing too much in memory and not using persistent storage properly for large files like image or the like? Too many possibilities, would need to post a new question about it.

Answer (score 0):

Let us assume you have location enabled so you just need the "user location" that you have saved in your table then try this:

Just pass your lang,lat and that should do it ^^

```
  func openMapForPlace() {

    var lat1 : NSString = self.venueLat
    var lng1 : NSString = self.venueLng

    var latitute:CLLocationDegrees =  lat1.doubleValue
    var longitute:CLLocationDegrees =  lng1.doubleValue

    let regionDistance:CLLocationDistance = 10000
    var coordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitute, longitute)
    let regionSpan = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coordinates, regionDistance, regionDistance)
    var options = [
        MKLaunchOptionsMapCenterKey: NSValue(MKCoordinate: regionSpan.center),
        MKLaunchOptionsMapSpanKey: NSValue(MKCoordinateSpan: regionSpan.span)
    ]
    var placemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinates, addressDictionary: nil)
    var mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: placemark)
    mapItem.name = "\(self.venueName)"
    mapItem.openInMapsWithLaunchOptions(options)

}
```

If there are any question feel free to ask

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer I do have the location enabled , I am not sure I understood what you meant, am I just supposed to copy this code to the button that opens the GPS ? if so, I do not have a member named "venueLat", "venueLng", or "venueName"